# External script with my template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, external

I cant figure out a way, how to make an external script in javascript for external usage, when i have my angularJS form with controller and other dependencies.

I made a local angularJS form, which uses angular material design Dialog service and i need to make an external script, which will open the same dialog, as it shows locally. Probably, i do not want external web apps to include angularJS and my whole app, i just need to open a Material Design dialog with my form and send information to my controller. Is it even possible ?

Also, i found something similar that probably could help me, but i dont know if it really will help me, because i need to include all my dependencies into that template ?

I would love to hear all your ideas and advices about this task.

Comment: Forgot to mention, i dont use jQuery.

Comment: Can you provide code from your attempts?

Comment: @goreorto there is one of the main problems, i dont even know in which direction to look. I have some ideas, how to make it, like, add my controller, app and dependencies in one file, then minify it, but this idea isnt very good, imo. The second idea is to load script, which will make an Ajax request and then input my template into the external web with all my dependencies. So basicly, i dont even have any code yet :/ Surfing on the google gave me an idea about making an angular external widget.

Comment: **or maybe i should use Iframe ?** I just dont know, so i am still waiting for any advices.

Comment: sorry, I don't think a completely understand the question. You have a non-angular site and you want to load a angular modal? I thought a code snippet may hint me on what you're trying to do

Comment: @goreorto not really. I have an external site (non angular), for example, myfriends.com and i have my own site: myweb.com. On myweb.com i have my own form, like, Add your review about myweb.com and i want to provide myfriends.com with similar script so they can add a review about myweb.com from myfriends.com. The whole idea is similar to facebook/google+/twitter and other "Like" buttons, they like open a form which user fills and then send information to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I've understood correctly.

What it does is, when you click the link, it inserts angular script tag, waits for it to load, inserts a couple divs for angular(these would be your modal), and finally bootstraps the angular app.

This is mostly vanilla JS

script.js

```
$('#launcher').click(function(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js';
    script.async = true;
    script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function() {
        var state = script.readyState;
        if ((!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            var divApp = document.createElement('div');
            var divCtrl = document.createElement('div');

            divApp.setAttribute("ng-app", "plunker");
            divCtrl.setAttribute("ng-controller", "MainCtrl");
            divApp.appendChild( divCtrl );
            divCtrl.innerHTML = "{{ name }}"; 

            body.insertBefore(divApp, body.firstChild);

            angular.module('plunker', [])
               .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
                 $scope.name = "Hello";
               })
            angular.bootstrap(divApp, ['plunker']);
        }
    };

    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);

});
```

index.html

```
<a href="#" id="launcher"> Launch Modal </a>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HWfrE0aJdH4uuMICaHrg?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, this is mostly IT! :) Thanks, will be playing with this, you helped me a lot.